# should i escape the parameters for the AddAddress function in PHPMailer?

Tags: phpmailer

Is there a need to escape the parameters in the "addaddress"-function in phpmailer using htmlentities ? the $email and the $name i mean, or is this done by phpmailer itself ?

Answer (score 0):

No. Email names have nothing to do with HTML. Just pass plain strings. If you need particular characters, use a character set that has them, such as UTF-8:

```
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```